# Are there any standard-layout guarantees for STL-containers?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, standard-layout

```
struct A {
   // ... some methods ...
   std::vector<int> foo;
   // ... more data members ...
};
```

With g++4.7 and libstdc++ I get `std::is_standard_layout<A>::value == true`.
But what happens with other compilers or standard-libraries?
Are there any guarantees that (at least certain?) STL-containers will not break the standard-layout?

Background:

```
struct B : A { // still standard-layout
   // ... more methods (but no new variables!)
   void bar();
};
```

This allows the use of `static_cast<B &>(a).bar()` even for `A a;`. (I'm not saying this is good design!).

Comment: The effect of `static_cast<B&>(a).bar()` is undefined. It may well "work" in the sense that it seems to do what you think it might do, but it is in no sense allowed by the language definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker Standard-layout guarantees that the address of the base class A is the same as the address of B. Therefore at least static_cast<B*>(&a)->bar() has to work. I not completely sure about using references, though

Comment: Um, no, that doesn't mean you can pretend that an object of a base type is an object of a derived type. Again, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Well, the thing is: A compiler does not have any leeway to make undefined things, because standard-layout fixes all the member-variable addresses, therefore every member-access in any of A's or B's methods is 'known-good' -- and all the fancy C++-stuff like virtual dispatch, etc. is excluded by the standard-layout definition. Anyway, my main question is more general than some (questionable) C++ magic to hack the Object-model (also volatile might be required there, to be "'safe'").

Comment: Standard layout is about being able to pass objects to other languages, which, presumably, don't know about "all the fancy C++ stuff". It does **not** mean that standard layout objects with the same layout can be treated as the same type. The standard simply does not require this to work.

Comment: I known that it's not required anywhere, but I also fail to see what could practically go wrong: Obviously B is never constructed, but AFAIK the default ctor without members does 'nothing'. Because of the interoperability requirement I can pass an A* to 'some old C function' and get a B* back, at least when I copy the data (`std::has_trivial_copy` comes to mind...). Or, maybe `sizeof(B)!=sizeof(A)`, but I can imagine that there's some C++ standard language that also rules this out. My goal is not to defend the code, but to better understand (implicit!) implications of the C and C++ standards.

Comment: As I said: the behavior is undefined. You can speculate about what your compiler might do, and you may well be right. But you may well be wrong, too. And I don't think there's any guarantee that when you pass an `A*` to some C function you can get a `B*` back, since C doesn't do inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there are no guarantees.

The C++11 Standard explicitly mentions when a class *must* have standard layout (e.g. the `mutex` class, the `atomic_flag` class, etc.).

The word "layout" does not appear in the whole Clause 23 (Containers Library). I believe this is sufficient to assume that no guarantees are given.